# How do I get the derived class from a interface?

Tags: c++, reflection, interface, entity-component-system

While trying to create an Entity-Component-System in C++, I have faced some problems regarding by lack of knowledge on the language.

With a class **Entity**, that holds the interface **IComponent** (which acts more like a flag that says "I hold data"), I have a method **Add** that adds a Component to the Entity if there is not another IComponent of the same class already in it.

Here's an oversimplified sample code:

```
struct IComponent{};

struct Foo : IComponent{ int x;};
struct Bar : IComponent{ int y; };

class Entity{
    vector<IComponent*> entityComponents;

    void Add(IComponent* componentToAdd){
        if("entityComponents" does not contain the class of "componentToAdd")
            entityComponents.add (componentToAdd)

    }
}
```

My expected result would be

```
Entity e;
Foo f;
Bar b;
Foo anotherF;

e.Add(f); // Works
e.Add(b); // Works
e.Add(anotherF); // Does not work because another 
                 //item in the array already inherits Foo
```

But I do not know how to get the base class of Foo and Bar from inside the IComponents list and check if they are repeated.

How may I get them? How may I cast an IComponent to a Foo if Foo is in the IComponent list?

Comment: `vector<IComponent>` You likely don't want that, but `vector<IComponent*>`. See also: [Object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)

Comment: What are you going to do with all those `IComponent` instances? Besides `Add`, how do you plan to use them?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My bad, fixed them. I'm planing on fetching them and modifying the data inside them. With stuff like GetComponent<Foo>(), HasComponent<Bar>(), RemoveComponent<Foo>()...

Comment: So, how do you plan to implement, say, `HasComponent<Bar>`? Once you know that, you would also know how to prevent duplicates in `Add`.

Comment: By checking if the class Bar is in the IComponent* list and them returning true, but I do not know how to do that. I'm afraid my question may a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). You can attempt to cast a pointer to base class to a pointer to a derived class. It fails if the instantiated object is not of type derived and in this case returns null.

Answer (score 1):

As [Bar Stool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730508/8592640) stated, my solution was

```
template<typename T>
bool HasComponent(){
  for(Component* component: this->components)
        if(T* casted = dynamic_cast<T*>(component))
                return true;           
  return false;

}
```

And later just check if "HasComponent()" is false and then add it

Comment: The double `if` is a bit confusing. :S You don't need to save the result :) Try:
`if (dynamic_cast<T*>(component)) return true;`